# Different colors for Title and Menus

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to set different colors for Title and Burger Menu Icon.
But no matter what combination I try, they always show up in same color.

This is what I am trying to achive :

[image]

colors.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="launcher_background">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#03213F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#63B34A</color>
</resources>
```

styles.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>

  </style>
  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#63B34A</item>
  </style>
  <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/avenir</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Toolbar.axml :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: try this
`toolbar.getOverflowIcon().setColorFilter(new BlendModeColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.green), BlendMode.SRC_ATOP));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the color of the icon on `Toolbar` .Add the following code in your custom Toolbar style .

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme">
   <!-- Used to tint the back arrow, menu and spinner arrow -->
   <item name="colorControlNormal">#f00</item>
   <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#0f0</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
<style name="CustomToolbarIconColor" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">INSERT_COLOR_HERE</item>
</style>
```

for changing the color of the toolbar icons.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app="@style/CustomToolbarIconColor"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```